# Why is Stability and Growth Pact still maintained?

Tags: european-union, economy

According to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_and_Growth_Pact) about Stability and Growth Pact there are many issues related to its implementation:

- unenforceable against big countries
- weakened in 2005 to waive France's and Germany's violations
- [Debt-to-GDP ratio is still increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_and_Growth_Pact#Member_states_by_SGP_criteria) for almost all countries that violate the 60% threshold for this indicator

Considering above I am wondering if the Pact is of any significant use.

**Question:** Why is Stability and Growth Pact still maintained?

Comment: The data you are linking is pretty outdated. [For the first time since the creation of the single currency, all euro area countries will have a deficit below 3% of GDP in 2018.](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-18-3845_en.htm) and actually for most eurozone countries the debt to gdp ratio is decreasing by now. (Your wikipedia source uses data from 2012!)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS - damn, you are right. Even Wikipedia article contains a warning related to outdated info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relies on outdated data (as clarified in the comments).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I think it is still on-topic, but an answer would take the outdated information into account.